# Knex.js, Nested '.orWhereExists' into filters field to include option for men, women or both

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, knex.js

I am using Knex and Postgres, NodeJS, Express & React.
I have a USERS table, a USERLIKS and a FILTERS table.
Where I am stuck is the gender query. 
Users can define in their filter that they are looking for male, female or both.

If I use '.orWhereExists' other filters such as the 2nd which stops you from  being returned users you've already liked/rejected are ignored. 
My gut says I should nest the gender query lines somehow and then change them to '.orWhereExists' but I am not sure how.

THANK YOU for all help. Just started coding this year and loving it but this problem has been a mind bender

```
Filters is organized like so 
  table.increments('id')   <-----primary
  table.integer('userid')  <-----foreign
  table.integer('min_age');
  table.integer('max_age');
  table.string('female');
  table.string('male');
```

```js
app.get('/api/potentials', (req, res) => {
  const cookieid = req.session.id
  console.log("potentials get for id ", cookieid)

    knex('users')
     .select('*')
     .whereNot('users.id', cookieid )
     .whereNotExists(knex.select('*').from('userlikes').whereRaw('userlikes.userid1 = ?', [cookieid]).andWhereRaw('users.id = userlikes.userid2'))
     .whereExists(knex.select('*').from('filters').whereRaw('users.gender = filters.female'))
     .whereExists(knex.select('*').from('filters').whereRaw('users.gender = filters.male'))
     .whereExists(knex.select('*').from('filters').whereRaw('users.age >= filters.min_age'))
     .whereExists(knex.select('*').from('filters').whereRaw('users.age < filters.max_age'))
     .then((result) => {
        console.log("filter result", result)
        res.send(result)
          })
    .catch((err) => {
            console.log("error", err)
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Knex function `.buildermodify()` that will work for your situation. See also: [documentation link](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify).

To use it, you create a function whose purpose is to conditionally add `.where` or other similar clauses to your knex query, and in the actual knex query, you call that function using `.buildermodify()`

**The sample from the documentation:**

```
var withUserName = function(queryBuilder, foreignKey) {
    queryBuilder.leftJoin('users', foreignKey, 'users.id')
        .select('users.user_name');
};

knex.table('articles')
    .select('title', 'body')
    .modify(withUserName, 'articles_user.id')
    .then(function(article) {
          console.log(article.user_name);
    });
```

**Applying it to your need to get gender (and ages):**

```
/* NEW FUNCTION TO DO THE SPECIAL FILTERING */
function customFiltering(queryBuilder, inputGender, minAge, maxAge) {

    if (inputGender === gender_is_female) { /* you need to fix this */

        /* THIS LINE IS THE SECRET SAUCE TO CONDITIONALLY UPDATE YOUR QUERY */
        /* queryBuilder.<my additional conditional clauses> */
        queryBuilder.whereExists( knex.select('*').from('filters')
                    .whereRaw('users.gender = filters.female'));
    } else if (inputGender === gender_is_male) {
        queryBuilder.whereExists( knex.select('*').from('filters')
                    .whereRaw('users.gender = filters.male'));
    }

    /* ADD MORE CODE HERE for the ages filter - minAge, maxAge */

};

knex('users')
 .select('*')
 .whereNot('users.id', cookieid )
 .whereNotExists( knex.select('*').from('userlikes').whereRaw('userlikes.userid1 = ?', [cookieid]).andWhereRaw('users.id = userlikes.userid2'))
 .modify(customFiltering, inputGender, minAge, maxAge)
 .then((result) => {
    console.log("filter result", result)
    res.send(result)
  })
 .catch((err) => {
    console.log("error", err)
 })
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do with complex query building is to write it in plain SQL and then trying to convert it into `knex` constructions.

As far as I understand you are looking for something like this

```
select
  *
from
  users as u
where
    ...
    and (
      (exists select * from filters as f where f.male = u.gender)
      or (exists select * from filters as f where f.female = u.gender)
    )
```

In knex words it can be written as

```
knex('users as u')
  .where('other conditions')
  .where((b) => {
    b
      .whereExists(knex.select('*').from('filters as f').whereRaw('u.gender = f.female'))
      .orWhereExists(knex.select('*').from('filters as f').whereRaw('u.gender = f.male'))
  })
```

There is a possibility in `knex` to group your where clauses in parentheses. Search [here](http://knexjs.org/) for "Grouped Chain"

Answer (score 0):

```
A solution someone offline gave me that worked was to use a "promise" but GaryL's solution above is more inline with what I was looking for. In the event it is helpful to people with similar questions this also worked.

> Blockquote
app.get('/api/potentials', (req, res) => {
  const cookieid = 1//req.session.id
  console.log("potentials get for id ", cookieid)
    Promise.all([
    knex('users')
     .select('filters.min_age','filters.max_age', 'filters.female','filters.male')
     .innerJoin('filters', 'users.id', 'filters.userid')
     .where('users.id',cookieid ),

    knex('users')
    .whereNotExists(knex.select('*').from('userlikes').whereRaw('userlikes.userid1 = ?', [cookieid]).andWhereRaw('users.id = userlikes.userid2'))
      ])

     .then((result) => {
        const[filterCriteria, users] = result
        const [min_age, max_age, female, male] = Object.values(filterCriteria[0])
          res.send(users.filter(user => {
           if((user.age >= min_age) && (user.age <= max_age) && ( (user.gender = female) || (user.gender = male) ||  (user.gender = female) && (user.gender = male) ) ) {
            return user
          }
        }))
      })
    .catch((err) => {
            console.log("error", err)
          })
      })
```